# Argue that MLE of GEO(p) is biased

Tags: self-study

Question: consider the case of having a random sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ from a $GEO(p)$ distribution adn recall that the MLE is given by $\hat{p}=1/\overline{X}$. Argue that the estimator $\hat{p}$ is biased but still consistent.

Answer (for now only regarding the biased part):

$\hat{p}$ is biased if $E\hat{p} \neq p$.

$$ \hat{p} = \frac{1}{\overline{X}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=i}^{n} X_i} = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=i}^{n} X_i} $$

Take the expectation on both sides:

$$ E\hat{p} = E
\left[ \frac{n}{\sum_{i=i}^{n} X_i} \right] = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=i}^{n} EX_i} = \frac{n}{n\mu} = \frac{1}{\mu} $$

$p = 1/\mu$, so

$$E\hat{p} = p$$

But this shows that the MLE estimator is unbiased. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $E(X),E(\frac{1}{X})$ both exist and $E(X)\ne 0$, keep in mind that in general $$E\left(\frac{a}{X}\right)=aE\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)\ne \frac{a}{E(X)}$$ for any constant $a$.

So you should have written $$E\left[\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\right]=n E\left[\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\right]$$

This means you had to use the distribution of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ to calculate the exact expectation of $\hat p$.

But to show the estimator is biased, you don't have to calculate the exact expectation. You can use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) instead to argue that $E\left(\frac{1}{\overline X}\right)$ is never equal to $E(\overline X)$.

Comment: Can you explain how to actually show this using Jensen's inequality? I looked at the Wikipedia page you linked and some video's on YouTube, but I don't understand how to demonstrate biasedness in this case.

Comment: The function $g(x)=1/x$ is convex for all $x>0$. Jensen's inequality says $E(g(X))>g(E(X))$ (equality does not hold as $g$ is not constant or linear).

Answer (score 1):

If the estimator is unbiased, it should be for all $n$. So, take $n=1$:
$$E[\hat{p}]=E\left[\frac{1}{X_1}\right]=\frac{1}{1}p+\frac{1}{2}p(1-p)+...>p$$
which means it is not equal to $p$, and biased. Note that, this is a contradiction and couldn't have been used to prove unbiasedness. Your mistake comes from $$E\left[\frac{1}{X}\right]\neq\frac{1}{E[X]}$$